# Am I correct about my intuitive understanding of Neyman-Pearson theorem?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I've been studying the Neyman-Pearson theorem and I want to know if my understanding about the relationship between test statistics and the significance level $\alpha$ is correct.
My problem to understand it's how we can come up with different cutoffs with the same $\alpha=0.05$. What I didn't realize is the cutoffs are related to the tests and not to the p.d.f. of the distribution (right?). Since the tests $T1$ and $T_2$ are different I can have different cutoffs $C_1$ and $C_2$ with the same $\alpha$.
In the context of the Neyman-Pearson theorem, I choose the most powerful test. Am I right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course.

$T_1$ and $T_2$ tests have their own distribution that you have to calculate. These distribution can obvioulsy be different from the  pdf of the original rv

Limiting the reasoning to a system of simple hypothesis (both simple), Neymann Pearson Lemma grants you to find the Most powerful of all possible tests, say a test with a higher power with respect to any other test with the same (or lower) size $\alpha$

You will see that in many case the distribution of the test can be very hard to find thus you will have to reason on some function of the distribution in order to find the cut off bound(s)

---

**Example**

Let's have the following population density

$$f(x,\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}$$

where $x \in [0;1]$,$\theta>0$,

Using a simple random sample $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ let's prove the following system

$$\begin{cases}
H_0: & \theta=1 \\
H_1: & \theta=2 
\end{cases}$$

**First Test**

I do not apply NP lemma, I choose a test by myself. I choose the following test

$T_1$: reject $H_0$ if $X_1>0.95$

(I do not mind I have 3 observation, I base my test only on the first observation $X_1$)

Let's calculate $\alpha$:

$$P(X_1>0.95|\theta=1)=\int_{0.95}^{1}dx=0.05$$

So my test has a Type I error of $5\%$...nice. Now let's calculate the power:

$$\gamma=P(X_1>0.95|\theta=2)=\int_{0.95}^{1}2x dx=0.0975\approx 10\%$$

**Second Test**

I apply NP lemma:

$$\frac{L(\mathbf{x}|\theta_0)}{L(\mathbf{x}|\theta_1)}\leq k$$

$$\frac{1}{8X_1X_2X_3}\leq k$$

taking the logarithm,

$$\Sigma_i(-log X_i)\leq c$$

Observing that $-log X_i\sim Exp(\theta)$

We have that the critical region is

$$Y\leq c$$

where $Y\sim Gamma(3;\theta)$ that is $2\theta Y\sim \chi_{(6)}^2$

Now to compare the two test, let's fix $\alpha=0.05$ also fot $T_2$

$$0.05=P(\chi_{(6)}^2<c) \rightarrow c=1.64$$

that is $Y=0.82$

Finally let's calculate $T_2$ power

$$\gamma=P(Y<0.82|\theta=2)=P(\chi_{(6)}^2<3.27)\approx 22.6\%$$

whichi is greater than $T_1$ power...

Comment: Thank you very much. On question, the critical values are from the test statistics, but the alpha is drawn from the pdf, right? just to make sure, I understood everything correctly

Comment: @user42912 : no. $\alpha$ is a given number. If you have to calculate it, given a critical region, you have to use the definition. Obviously as the critical region comes out from a reasoning (i.e. applying NP Lemma or other reasoning) it is not necessarily drawn from your original pdf. I think you have Mood Graybill Boes...there you can find a lot of similar solved problems. I added an example I  invented right now. Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, thank you very much again. So the only reason I use the pdf is to try to answer the hypothesis test regarding the unknown parameter using the test statistics (if I can find a good one, as you said sometimes it's very difficult) and once I have it, I work only with the test statistics, the probabilities, alpha, critical values, etc.